# Kotlin not configured after updating android studio & gradle plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

This is the build.gradle project file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

This is build.gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ze.app.xyzmath"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding { enabled = true }
}

dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:19.3.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
}
```

[Android gradle plugin version (4.0.1) & gradle version (6.5.1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XewQs.png)

I also cannot open File->Settings, I click it but no window opens.

I have tried "Configure Kotlin for Project" and it says no configurators are available.

I have tried rebuild, clean , invalidate & restart.

I have tried many previous solutions on stackoverflow but none have been successful.

I still have the Kotlin not configured issue, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - delete .AndroidStudio4.0 directory in C:\Users\YourUserName

Android Studio will create automatically new one, problem free.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new activity using kotlin lang , it will configure kotlin automatically